# Intent keeps failing for android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

anyone know why this intent is failing

Here is the log in the log cat

```
04-08 10:52:51.782: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10411): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans  cannot have a zero length
04-08 10:52:51.782: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10411): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length 
04-08 10:52:52.542: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10411): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-08 10:52:52.542: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10411): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   activity ComponentInfo   {com.better.work.learning.letters.and.more.awesome/com.better.work.learning.letters.and.more.awesome.spellingLevel1}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x16
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x16
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1026)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:671)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:14494)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at com.better.work.learning.letters.and.more.awesome.spellingLevel1.onCreate(spellingLevel1.java:72)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    ... 11 more
```

Code keeps failing here is the manifest file

that's not the complete code but basically there are no errors on the code it just fails when I try to load u the sellingLevel1 class which extends activity and is imported.  It is also included into the package as everything else.  Also the app runs but doesn't fails when I click button 1 on the spellingLevelPicker class

EDIT

ok its failing here

public class spellingLevel1 extends Activity {

```
Context mContext = null;
private RelativeLayout mCanvasContainer;
private SCanvasView mSCanvas;
private ImageView mImageView1,mImageView2,mImageView3,mImageView4,mImageView5,mImageView6,mImageView7,mImageView8;
public int currentLetter;
private int rando;
int[] myImageList = {
        R.drawable.lettersa, R.drawable.lettersb,
        R.drawable.lettersc, R.drawable.lettersd,
        R.drawable.letterse, R.drawable.lettersf, R.drawable.lettersg,
        R.drawable.lettersh, R.drawable.lettersi, R.drawable.lettersj,
        R.drawable.lettersk, R.drawable.lettersl, R.drawable.lettersm,
        R.drawable.lettersn, R.drawable.letterso, R.drawable.lettersp,
        R.drawable.lettersq, R.drawable.lettersr, R.drawable.letterss, R.drawable.letterst,
        R.drawable.lettersu, R.drawable.lettersv, R.drawable.lettersw,
        R.drawable.lettersx, R.drawable.lettersy, R.drawable.lettersz};





/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spelling);

    mContext = this;
    mCanvasContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.canvas_container);
    mSCanvas = new SCanvasView(mContext);




ImageView mImageView01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);       
ImageView mImageView02 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);       
ImageView mImageView03 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);       
ImageView mImageView04 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);       
ImageView mImageView05 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);       
ImageView mImageView06 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);       
ImageView mImageView07 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);       
ImageView mImageView08 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);       
Random rando = new Random();


currentLetter = rando.nextInt(myImageList.length);

mImageView01.setBackgroundResource(currentLetter);
mImageView02.setBackgroundResource(currentLetter);
mImageView03.setBackgroundResource(currentLetter);
mImageView04.setBackgroundResource(currentLetter);

}
```

}

Theres a public void on destroy below but if I comment the imageview set background resources out it doesn't fail

Comment: dont use v.context as context, instead go for getApplicationContext, or this or getActivity or classname.this

Comment: Check the resources you're invoking in spellingLevel1. One of them is probably misspelled (better yet: post your code for that class)

Comment: going to lunch will be back later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines in your logcat

```
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:671)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:14494)
04-08 10:52:53.797: E/AndroidRuntime(10411):    at com.better.work.learning.letters.and.more.awesome.spellingLevel1.onCreate(spellingLevel1.java:72)
```

tell me your problem is one of the drawables you're trying to instance in your onCreate method. Check the list of drawables you're including in your file structure to verify you have all the drawables you're listing. (And debug the value you're getting when you're failing)

Instead of

```
currentLetter = rando.nextInt(myImageList.length);
```

(which will give you a value between 0 and myImageList.length -1) you need to use

```
currentLetter = myImageList[rando.nextInt(myImageList.length)];
```

(which will give you the int that was generated for your drawable resources)

Comment: im only calling the letters in that class and when I do that, they are there in the drawable folder.  Because they have been called in other classes as well

Comment: basically something is glitching because the drawables are there, they have been called by another class and worked properly, I think its because the drawables are setting the background to the imageview and that's why its not working properly

Comment: I took commented out the imageView01.setBackgroundResources(currentLetter) and it works, so that's where its failing

Comment: the next 3 all the setbackground resources lines

Comment: I figured it out.  My pictures I was calling were too large therefor it woukdnt fit in the layout giving me an error

Answer (score 0):

first create a `private Context context` as a member of your class.

Then in the onCreate add this : `this.context = context;`

or if you're in a view class you can pass the Context from activity to your constructor so it'll like this

```
public className(Context context) {
     this.context = context;
}
```

and the final is change this

```
mLevel1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), spellingLevel1.class); //Coming soon 
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);        

        }
        });
```

to this

```
mLevel1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, spellingLevel1.class); //Coming soon 
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);        

        }
        });
```

I hope this will answer your question :)
if you have any question regarding my answer feel free to ask in the comment :)

Comment: my question is, I have the same exact code (just changing the spellinglevel.class to this class) right before it and it works ill show you in the next comment

Comment: @RichTalcik OK please post your spellingLevel1 class here -> https://gist.github.com/ thanks

Comment: post the layout as well (xml)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is nothing in the code os wrong the pictures I was callinf are too big and are colliding with the other imageviews therefor causinf the error of the drawable resources

Comment: Ok I havent fully tested it yet but I will